# Afinal K, W e Y fazem ou não parte do alfabeto usado na língua portuguesa?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico, mudanças-históricas

Sou relativamente novo, então durante meu período de escola passei por varias mudanças no alfabeto que eu conhecia, alguns professores me disseram que K, W e Y faziam parte do alfabeto, anos depois esses mesmos professores me disseram que os mesmos não faziam parte, porém depois me disseram novamente que faziam. Isso deixou muitos colegas meus e inclusive a mim muito confusos.

> Então o que as regras da língua portuguesa dizem a respeito oficialmente?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

De acordo com o [*Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa de 1990*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?acordo&version=1990), sim, fazem parte do alfabeto.

**BASE I: DO ALFABETO E DOS NOMES PRÓPRIOS ESTRANGEIROS E SEUS DERIVADOS**

1. O alfabeto da língua portuguesa é formado por vinte e seis letras, cada uma delas com uma forma minúscula e outra maiúscula:
   [image]

Obs.:

1. Além destas letras, usam-se o ç (cê cedilhado) e os seguintes dígrafos: rr (erre duplo), ss (esse duplo), ch (cê-agá), lh (ele-agá), nh (ene-agá), gu (guê-u) e qu (quê-u).
2. Os nomes das letras acima sugeridos não excluem outras formas de as designar.

2   As letras k, w e y usam-se nos seguintes casos especiais:
a) Em antropónimos/antropônimos originários de outras línguas e seus deriva­dos: Franklin, frankliniano; Kant, kantismo; Darwin, darwinismo; Wagner, wagneriano; Byron, byroniano; Taylor, taylorista;

b) Em topónimos/topônimos originários de outras línguas e seus derivados: Kwanza, Kuwait, kuwaitiano; Malawi, malawiano;

c) Em siglas, símbolos e mesmo em palavras adotadas como unidades de medida de curso internacional: TWA, KLM; K-potássio (de kalium), W-oeste (West); kg-quilograma, km-quilómetro, kW-kilowatt, yd-jarda (yard); Watt.

Comment: Adenda: em Portugal, o `w` chama-se "duplo-vê"; e o `y` também pode ser chamado "i grego".

Comment: @ANeves interessante a similaridade com nome em inglês, 'Duplo-U'.

Answer (score 14):

Confusão comum.

O [alfabeto oficial brasileiro](http://www.numaboa.com.br/escolinha/garranchos/90-escrita/294-alfabeto-ocidental?tmpl=component&print=1&page=) original tinha 23 letras.
Isso se deve ao fato de que não existe qualquer palavra de língua portuguesa que utilize **W**, **K** ou **Y**

Porém no **acordo ortográfico de 1990** foi instituído o [alfabeto latino](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_latino) de 26 letras que deriva do padrão [ISO/IEC 646](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet).

Note que esse padrão ISO foi criado para uso em informática e por isso se difundiu amplamente. Esse padrão foi bolado inicialmente para suprir as necessidades da língua inglesa e por isso possui W (originalmente duplo V), K e Y.

Além disso note que outros alfabetos de origem latina podiam ser (originalmente) ainda menores - como o italiano, que não possui o **J** (que é uma letra derivada do **I**).

Comment: **Qual** padrão [ISO](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Internacional_para_Padroniza%C3%A7%C3%A3o)? Existem [muitos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_normas_ISO)!

Comment: ISO é um acrônimo para um consórcio de instituições com objetivo de criar diversos padrões, em diversas áreas (muito atuante em informatica).  Se vc seguir os links que deixei na resposta vai chegar ao [ISO/IEC 646: basic latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet)

Comment: Acrescenta esse link na resposta.

Answer (score 12):

Fazem parte apenas teoricamente, porque na prática são apenas para dar "suporte" a termos em línguas estrangeiras (como o inglês, por exemplo), nomes que usam essas letras (seja de pessoas ou lugares) e siglas (como KM, por exemplo).
Ou seja, na língua portuguesa não existem palavras não estrangeiras que usam essas letras.

Por exemplo,  termos como "download" que usa `w`, "karaokê", que usa `k`, yin-yang que usa `y`, entre outros.